# Ошибка public_key is a required field при подключении liqpay

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь подключить оплату через liqpay на сайт, но вылазит такая ошибка:

> public_key is a required field

Она указывает на **строчку**

```
 <%=liqpay_button @liqpay_request %>
```

В **файле show**

```
<% if @place.status == false %>
  <p>If you have paid already, the response didn't come in yet from LiqPAY. Refresh this page later.</p>
  <%=liqpay_button @liqpay_request %>
<% elsif @place.status == true %>
  <p>Payment succeeded.</p>
<% else %>
  <p>Payment failed.</p>
<% end %>
```

Код контроллера places_controller.rb

```
 if @place.status == false
  @liqpay_request = Liqpay::Request.new(
    :amount => @searched_film_session_price,
    :currency => 'UAH',
    :name => @place_title,
    :order_id => @place.id,
    :result_url => place_url(@place)
    # :server_url => liqpay_payment_place_url(@place)
  )
```

В файле config/initializers/liqpay.rb прописал:

```
Liqpay.default_options = {
    public_key: ENV['публичный ключ полученный при регистрации'],
    private_key: ENV['приватный ключ полученный при регистрации'],
    currency: 'UAH'
}
```

Код payments_controller.rb

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :liqpay_payment

  def liqpay_payment
    @liqpay_response = Liqpay::Response.new(params)
    @place = Place.find(@liqpay_response.order_id)

    @place.data = {}

(Liqpay::Response::ATTRIBUTES - %w(public_key sender_phone transaction_id)).each do |attribute|
    @place.data[attribute] = @liqpay_response.send(attribute)
end

    if @liqpay_response.success?
      @place.update_attributes!(:status => true)
    else
      @place.update_attributes!(:status => false)
    end
    redirect_to @place
  rescue Liqpay::InvalidResponse
    render text: 'Payment error', status: 500
  end
end
```

Comment: Максим, перенесите, пожалуйста, своё решение из вопроса в ответ.

Comment: @Саша Черных Сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Надеюсь, вы это не успели закоммитить.

*Никогда, **никогда** не храните конфиденциальные данные (пароли, ключи, логины к сторонним сервисам) прямо в коде приложения.*

`ENV` это объект для доступа к **переменным среды**. Они являются **традиционным** средством хранения конфигурации на [12-факторных платформах](http://12factor.net/config) вроде Heroku. [Не идеальным](https://gist.github.com/telent/9742059), но сносным.

Переменная среды это пара *название-значение* `ENV[название] #=> значение`, название придумайте сами, чтобы выражение `ENV[...]` выглядело осмысленно. Те же правила, что при именовании переменных: называйте так, чтобы с первого взгляда было понятно, каково назначение значения выражения.

**Должно стать понятно, почему `ENV[ключ]` не работало: в среде не было переменной с таким названием и это выражение возвращало `nil`.**

---

Как задавать переменные среды, зависит от платформы. На Heroku есть отдельная секция в настройках приложения, а локально... тут целая история, хранить переменные среды для нескольких приложений на одной машине разработчика не очень весело, поэтому обычно применяют **обёртки** над *файлами конфигурации* с `ENV` в роли "запасного плана" (если нет файла конфигурации).

Путь к файлу конфигурации прописывается в `.gitignore`, поэтому наружу никогда не попадает, а в продакшене вообще отсутствует, поэтому используется `ENV`.

Я предпочитаю [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) ([пример использования](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server)), но также есть [`config`](https://github.com/railsconfig/config).

Comment: Я понял это ещё до того, как написал ответ на вопрос, просто не правильно сформулировал мысль)

Comment: @MaximCherevatov вы имейте в виду, что сюда будут приходить случайные люди и читать то, что мы тут понаписали. Это управление довольно опасной информацией, с формулировками надо быть осторожнее .-.

Comment: Я Вас понял, буду осторожнее.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в ENV. Я прописал полученные ключи прямо в это поле.

**Update**

Меня не правильно поняли, я не советовал писать туда значения напрямую, а уточнил, что я так сделал с самого начала и это оказалось ошибкой!! Я исправил её подключив гем 'figaro' !

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/80311)

Comment: @totorro это исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, хотя это и рубрика `#вредные_советы`.