# Как лучше работать с конфигурациями в Ruby

Tags: ruby, config, configuration, best-practice

Допустим, у нас есть некая структура конфигурации (взята из `YAML`, `JSON`, `XML` или просто в виде `Hash`):

```
configuration = {
  gmail: {
    username: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: 'pa$$word',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    ssl: true,
    port: 993
  },
  ftp: {
    username: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: 'pa$$word',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    ssl: true,
    port: 42
  }
}
```

Далее, на основе этой структуры мы достаём из неё данные:

```
mail = Mail.new host: configuration[:gmail][:host], port: configuration[:gmail][:port], username: configuration[:gmail][:username], password: configuration[:gmail][:password], ssl: configuration[:gmail][:ssl]
ftp = FTP.new host: configuration[:ftp][:host], port: configuration[:ftp][:port], username: configuration[:ftp][:username], password: configuration[:ftp][:password], ssl: configuration[:ftp][:ssl]
```

Всё работает, но сам код получается «плохочитаемым». 
Т. е. он конечно понятен, но слишком много «сухого» текста, вместо привычного для языка программирования кода.

Поделитесь `Best Practice`, как правильно делать и использовать конфигурации в `Ruby`.

Comment: Вам может помочь [вот этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522445/181100). Не могу сходу сказать, дубликат ваш вопрос или нет.

Answer (score 3):

Если имена атрибутов Mail и FTP в вашем примере в точности соответствуют ключам в структурах в конфигурации - вы можете передавать в конструктор хеш напрямую:

```
mail = Mail.new configuration[:gmail]
ftp = FTP.new configuration[:ftp]
```

Здесь важно помнить две вещи:

- Ключи и типы значений в конфигурации должны совпадать с атрибутами и типами значений атрибутов класса;
- Доступ к конфигурации должен быть только у вас - иначе злоумышленник может, оперируя структурой, создавать объекты с любыми атрибутами класса без ограничений.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, как минимум вы **написали выбор поднабора из хэша с захардкоженными ключами**. "Колонна" в вашем коде (которая получается, если код "подровнять"):

```
mail = Mail.new     host: configuration[:gmail][:host],
                    port: configuration[:gmail][:port],
                username: configuration[:gmail][:username],
                password: configuration[:gmail][:password],
                     ssl: configuration[:gmail][:ssl]
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ это ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...на самом деле же просто хэшмап. Просто `{}` вокруг него писать оказалось необязательно, т. к. это последний аргумент вызова метода, и это особый случай в синтаксисе Ruby.

Если в `configuration[:gmail]` нет лишних ключей, то можно сделать попросту вот так:

```
Mail.new configuration[:gmail]
```

...а если лишние ключи хочется отрезать, и вы вооружены `aсtivesupport`'ом (гем такой, из состава Rails), есть `Hash#slice`:

```
# Точечная загрузка ActiveSupport
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/slice'
# В Rails необязательно, там он обычно весь уже загружен

Mail.new configuration[:gmail].slice(:host, :port, :username, :password, :ssl)
```

...но обычно один набор параметров конфигурации используется в ровно одном месте (или если в нескольких, то как минимум одинаково: скажем, при вызове однотипных конструкторов), поэтому можно себе позволить просто не писать в конфигах лишние ключи.

Это не конвенция, такая ситуация сложилась сама и она всех устраивает.

"Best bractices" конфигураций, которые вы ждёте, этого всего в основном не касаются и они запакованы, в разных комбинациях, в гемы `dotenv`, `figaro` и `config`. Что в них типично встречается:

- Сокращённый синтаксис получения конфигурации ключей: `a[:b][:c]` => `a.b.c`
- Фоллбэк (когда конфига нет) к переменным среды в `ENV` (см. [12-факторные приложения](https://12factor.net/ru/))
- Конвенции по размещению конфигурационных файлов и их формату — кто на что горазд